Resetting/reusing a TaskCompletionSource
I have ClassA that has a property called GetData that returns a TaskCompletionSource Task:
private TaskCompletionSource<Data> _taskCompletionSource = new();
public Task<Data> GetData => _taskCompletionSource.Task;

There is also a method called DataRetrieved where I set the result (let's assume the data retrieval always returns a valid result, no timing out or exceptions):
public void DataRetrieved
{
  ...
  _data = retrievedData;
  _taskCompletionSource.SetResult(_data);
  ...
}

ClassA also has a Reset method.  The point of this method is for ClassA to clear its data and retrieve it again from the data source.  It is here that I want to "reset" the _taskCompletionSource so that I can be used again.
public void Reset()
{
  _data = null;
  _taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Data>();
  //Make the call to get fresh data which will eventually call DataRetrieved and _taskCompletionSource.SetResult again...
}

Other classes will use ClassA like so:
await _classA.GetData;

I am not sure how to handle the case where Reset is called but some class may already be awaiting GetData.  I can check if _taskCompletionSource.Task.IsCompleted, IsFaulted, or IsCanceled and if so I believe I can just recreate _taskCompletionSource.  But what should I do if it is in none of those states?
My main goal is to have consumers calling GetData to block until the data is available.  So my first thought went to asyc/await.

so consumers can call the public Reset?

"I am not sure how to handle the case where Reset() is called but some class may already be awaiting GetData..." - I'd just do throw new InvalidOperationException( "Cannot reset when the current Task has pending Continuations." ); or similar.

why not have a queue of TaskCompletiounSources?

@IvanPetrov Yes, consumers can call the public Reset method.  I will update the question to clarify that.  You mention using a queue of TaskCompletionSources.  I am not sure what you mean.  Do you have an example?

@Dai I can do that but how can I tell if the Task has pending continuations vs no consumer ever actually calling GetData?

@Flack your question reminded me of code I read in this blogpost which I think you'd maybe find helpful

basically, why not maintain more than one TaskCompletiounSource in ClassA that each returns Task
